# How to disable CTRL+RSHIFT/CTRL+LSHIFT shortkeys?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot find a solution to disable it. (the shortcut changes the text input reading direction to left->right or right->left.

Now i can make it happen only in Notepad, but I've got it working on other text inputs before! Not sure if there is also some other shortcut for the same thing.

Comment: you want to define another key or disable it ?? If it is to disable then check my answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### In Windows XP

> **1)** Go to **Start** >> Click on **Control Panel** >> Open **Regional and Language Options**
>
> **2)**  Under Languages Tab , Un-Check "**Install Files for Complex script
>   and right to left languages (including
>   thai)**"
>
> [image]
>
> 3) Click **Apply** and **OK**
>
> 4) **Restart** Computer

Comment: And what happens if he wants the language and just wants to disable the hotkey!?

Comment: indeed, i dont want to remove the support for other languages

Comment: @Wil In XP even if you set the key to none in key settings it wont be disabled, thats why I posted this , I myself tried it and finally figured the only way I could disable was un-check tight-to-left languages

Comment: I know it works, I tested it and posted here. Yet I got Down-votes :(

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Control Panel` > `Regional and Languages` (or similar) and then the keyboard tab.

Look there for `Advanced Key Settings` or similar and you should be able to configure keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

(Picture from Windows 7, I do not currently have a Windows XP box to test/direct you on).

edit - update for comment
[image]

Comment: i cant find it on XP... no such menu

Comment: @Neeb, please look at updated picture - this is from Windows 2003, however it should be the same as Windows XP. It is disabled on mine because I only have one language, but please see if you have the option there.

Comment: i have only one language set too, so i cant click "key settings"

Comment: please upvote the correct answer, it worked :)